# How to create a empty row when a user hits a tab key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('table').on('keydown', function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode !== 9) return;
    var $this = $(this),
        $lastTr = $('tr:last', $('table')),
        $lastTd = $('td:last', $lastTr);
    if (($(e.target).closest('td')).is($lastTd)) {
        $lastTr.after($lastTr.clone());
    }
});
```

This is my code..It creates a row with existing datas but i want a empty row..what i have to alter in my code..thanks in advance

Comment: You need to reset the data in the cloned instance `$lastTr.clone()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your previous posted question you've input's inside the cloned `tr`, so you could reset those field using `.val('')`, like :

```
if (($(e.target).closest('td')).is($lastTd)) {
    var cloned = $lastTr.clone();
    cloned.find('input').val('');

    $lastTr.after(cloned);
}
```

Comment: @esakkichandra that answers your question?

Comment: a new row is create in vertical,but i want in horizonal format.